# possible values of $\gcd{(5n+9,3n+3)}$ for every positive integer $n$

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I have tried to determine the values of $\gcd{(5n+9,3n+3)}$ for every positive integer n , but i'm not able to set all of them , I have took $a-b=\gcd{(a,b)}=2(n+3)$ then n+3|a-b then $a-b= (n+3) k$ , k is integer number then $\gcd{(a,b)}=(n+3)k$ , by this way it must give values for $k$ and $n$ , it's hard for me to get the possible values of $\gcd{(5n+9,3n+3)}$, **Then Is there any possible way to get $\gcd{(5n+9,3n+3)}$ for every positive integer $n$**?

Comment: Well, we know the $\gcd$ is  a divisor of $4n = 3\times (3n+3)-(5n+9)$.  Also it is a divisor of $12=3\times (5n+9)-5\times (3n+3)$...

Answer (score 2):

Using repeatedly the identity $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,a-b)$ we get:

$$\begin{align}
\gcd(5n+9,3n+3)&=\gcd(3n+3,2n+6)\\
&=\gcd(2n+6,n-3)\\
&=\gcd(n-3,n+9)\\
&=\gcd(n+9,12)
\end{align}$$

So this gcd is:

- $1$ if $n\equiv 2,4,8,10\pmod{12}$
- $2$ if $n\equiv 1,5\pmod{12}$
- $3$ if $n\equiv 0,6\pmod{12}$
- $4$ if $n\equiv 7,11\pmod{12}$
- $6$ if $n\equiv 9\pmod {12}$
- $12$ if $n\equiv 3\pmod{12}$

Comment: It's worth noting that the sequence of GCDs you compute at first are not magic, they are the result of the Euclidean algorithm applied to the coefficients of $n$ in order to cancel them out as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If $d=\gcd{(5n+9,3n+3)}$ then $d|3n+3, 5n+9$ and hence
$$d|(5n+9)-(3n+3)=2n+6 \\
d|3n+3-(2n+6)=n-3 \\
d|2n+6-2(n-3)=12$$

Now, for each **potential** value you have to check if you can find an $n$ such that the gcd is exactly that value.